# Unable to exclude unwanted file extensions while grabbing emails using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've written a script in python using `regular expression` to grab email address from certain websites. I've used selenium as few of the sites are dynamic. However, my script is doing fine as long as there is no such file extensions resembling email available in those pages, as in `himalayan-institute-logo@2x.png`.

***How can I exclude extensions ending with `.png` or `.jpg` while grabbing emails?***

Regex pattern I've made use of:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+
```

Script I'm trying with:

```
import re
from selenium import webdriver

URLS = (
    'https://www.himalayaninstitute.org/about/',
    'http://www.innovaprint.com.sg/',
    'http://www.cityscape.com.sg/?page_id=37',
    'http://www.yogaville.org',
    )

def get_email(driver,link):
    driver.get(link)
    email = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+',driver.page_source)
    if email: 
        print(link,email[0])
    else: 
        print(link)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chromeOptions.add_argument("--headless")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions)
    for url in URLS:
        get_email(driver,url)
    driver.quit()
```

Output I'm having:

```
https://www.himalayaninstitute.org/about/ himalayan-institute-logo@2x.png
http://www.innovaprint.com.sg/ info@innovacoms.com
http://www.cityscape.com.sg/?page_id=37 info@cityscape.com.sg
http://www.yogaville.org Yantra-@500.png
```

Comment: Check this https://regex101.com/r/GhQnu8/1/

Comment: I tried your suggested expression @Code Maniac. This time I don't get any file extensions. However, I don't get any email either.

Comment: Can you just show me a sample your getting in driver.page_source

Comment: Ain't there any way to let the regex exclude only those extensions from grabbing? `driver.page_source` may not always be the same if I later try with another site.

Comment: Try adding `\b` at front and end of the regex pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last part `[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+` is a broad match which does not take the position of the dot into account. It could for example also match `.....`

One possibility could be to still use the first part of your pattern `[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@` to match including the @ sign.

Then use a positive lookahead to assert what is on the right does not end with .png or .jpg and match a pattern where the dot is between at least 1 character that is not a dot.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*(?!\.(?:png|jpg))\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

**Explanation**

- `[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@` Match allowed character followed by @
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` Match any of the listed in the character class
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+` Match a dot followed by 1+ times what is listed in the character class
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what follows is not

  - `\.(?:png|jpg)` Match .png or .jog
- `)\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+` Close lookahead and match 1+ times a dot and what is listed in the character class

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hgS4tu/1)

Comment: Applying your suggestion within the script I'm still having the exact same result I was having earlier @The fourth bird.

Comment: @robots.txt Was the example helpful?

Comment: It would be helpful If my above script also produced the same output as your's (what you have shown in the demo) @The fourth bird . Thanks.

Comment: @robots.txt I see, I have updated my answer. Try this updated version `[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*(?!\.(?:png|jpg))\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+`

Comment: Perfectly awesome @The fourth bird. Can you make a comment why it was not working earlier. Thanks.

Comment: In my previous answer I assumed that what follows the email could not be a non whitespace char, which is not the case.